# Checking the number of miles

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to check the number of miles of products. And if it is 1 it need to be

> mile

, if is more than 1 it need to be

> miles

Can anybody help me?

```
<span class="text-red">
    if(<?= $this->product->getMiles() ?> == 1) {
        <span><?= $this->product->getMiles() ?> mile</span>
    } else {
        <span><?= $this->product->getMiles() ?> miles</span>
    }
</span>
```

Comment: Almost everything is wrong with this code.

Comment: Your PHP tags need to go around the `if ` and `else` statements

Comment: @JammyDodger231 No shorthand tags.

Comment: Actually looking at the output of this code will yield a *big* clue to the problem...

Comment: @Daan what do you mean no shorthand tags you can do either?

Comment: @JammyDodger231 No you can't, you can't do `<?= if(1 == 1) { //do } ?>`

Comment: @Daan I just meant a normal PHP short tag not the tag to return something

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
<span class="text-red">
  <span><?= ($this->product->getMiles() == 1) ? $this->product->getMiles()." mile" : $this->product->getMiles()." miles"; ?></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` code should be wrapped inside the `<?php ?>` tags. It should be -

```
<span class="text-red">
    <?php if($this->product->getMiles() == 1) { ?>
        <span><?php echo $this->product->getMiles() ?> mile</span>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <span><?php echo $this->product->getMiles() ?> miles</span>
    <?php } ?>
</span>
```